# Migrate a C program to Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am a beginner with C/C++ and the Android NDK, and I have a problem trying to create a native library. My code compiles using MinGW on CDT, but when I write the same code on a JNI file, there is an error.

My code is:

```
int n = 7;
int positions[n];   
int final_order[n];

memcpy(positions, final_order,sizeof(final_order));
```

The plugin shows me:

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void * memcpy(void *, const void *, ?)'
```

This the header from MinGW on CDT:

```
_CRTIMP void* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW   memcpy (void*, const void*, size_t);
```

This the header from the Android NDK:

```
extern void*  memcpy(void *, const void *, size_t);
```

Comment: Have you added `#include <string.h>` at the beginning of file?

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko yes, there is a #include <string.h>

Comment: Note that this is not a compiler error from the ndk, but rather the unnecessary eclipse plugin being pedantic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton there is a way to change this on plugin? to ignore?

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to change the C plugin's behavior, but I find it simpler to disable (or more accurately, never even install) the plugin.  The NDK's actual compiler is distinct from the plugin, which is a relatively recent addition to the tool set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a known indexing problem when using Eclipse to do NDK development.

Read about it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

Near the bottom there is a reasonable workaround that I myself use:

> What we want is to use the Android GCC toolchain but change the actual tools and modify the discovery options so that the include paths and symbols are correct.
>
> Go into C/C++ Buid \ Tool Chain editor
>
> Make sure Android GCC is the selected toolchain and Android Builder is the selected builder.
>
> Click on "Select Tools"
>   Select "Allow all changes"
>   Remove the Android GCC Compiler
>   Add "GCC C Compiler" and "GCC C++ Compiler" so that we can index both c and cpp headers.
>
> If you would look at "Paths and Symbols" you would see we have both GNU C and GNU C++ languages, but of course the built-in include paths are wrong. luckily there is a fix for that.
>
> Go into C/C++ Build \ Discovery Options
>   Change Discovery profiles scope to "Configuration-wide"
>   Make sure the Discovery profile is using "AndroidPerProjectProfile" and make sure both checkboxes are checked.

I then have to manually add my own include directories and definies under `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols`

It's worth noting that your code **compiles** fine. You can turn off indexing if you like, but if you still want the advantages of indexing you'll have to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is:

to open the `android native` perspective,

to right-click on your project in the `project navigator`,

and to click on the `index` options to rebuild the indices.