# NEON intrinsic types work in C but throw invalid arguments error in C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, neon, intrinsics

I have problems with using NEON intrinsics and inline assembly in Android NDK.

NEON types like `float32x4_t` give an "invalid arguments" error when compiling C++ code with GCC 4.6 and 4.8, however, the code compiles fine if compiled as C.

For example, here's some code:

```
inline float32x4_t VectorAdd(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b)
{
  return vaddq_f32(a, b);
}
```

I get two errors here:

- In the function itself: `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: ? vaddq_f32(?, ?) '`.
- Where the function is called: `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: ? VectorAdd(?, ?) '`.

All NEON types are displayed as ? in the error message, while non-NEON types are displayed correctly.

What is also strange is that functions which only use NEON types as return values (for example, `vld1q_f32` and my abstract wrapper of it) don't suffer from the error.

I tried the same code in [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org) 4.6 and 4.5, and there is no error, and correct and optimized assembly is generated, however, it doesn't work with Android NDK.

Comment: This might be a silly question... but are these eclipse indexing errors or are they compiler errors? I.e. if you use ndk-build from the command line do you get the exact errors as described?

Comment: Oh, yes, it's an Eclipse bug. I checked the console, everything built fine.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a known eclipse indexing bug when using CDT with ADT - I talked about it in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924184/migrate-a-c-program-to-android-ndk/18277247#18277247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, in Window / Preferences / C/C++ / Code Analysis, set the Severity of "Invalid Arguments" errors to Warning, so that these bogus errors won't prevent launching the application.