# android ndk development issue: 'Invalid arguments' error for memcpy function

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I used a c++ code for android project, so I use the NDK tools.
The IDE is eclipse.
When compile the project, I got the error for `memcpy` function:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void * memcpy(void *, const void *, ?)
'
```

It happens for `malloc`, `strftime` too.

I developed under Windows system.

Why?

Here is part of my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include "dirent.h"

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

string getCurrentDate() {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    // #######################error part
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", timeinfo);

    string timeStr(buffer);

    return timeStr;
}

std::string jstring2str(JNIEnv* env, jstring jstr) {
    char* rtn = NULL;
    jclass clsstring = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jstring strencode = env->NewStringUTF("GB2312");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clsstring, "getBytes",
            "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
    jbyteArray barr = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(jstr, mid, strencode);
    jsize alen = env->GetArrayLength(barr);
    jbyte* ba = env->GetByteArrayElements(barr, JNI_FALSE);
    if (alen > 0) {
        // ####################error for malloc
        rtn = (char*) malloc(alen + 1);
        // ####################error for memcpy
        memcpy(rtn, ba, alen);
        rtn[alen] = 0;
    }
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(barr, ba, 0);
    std::string stemp(rtn);
    free(rtn);
    return stemp;
}
...
```

Comment: Did you include the proper header file?

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we get to know what is gone wrong in the code. Also post the headers that you have included.

Comment: @Retired Ninja, Yes, I have include `string.h`, `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`

Comment: @Zax, ok, I will post some code to my question.

Comment: You're missing the definition of size_t.  Getting CDT configured right for that (and some other basic types, like int32_t) can be a pain.

Comment: @fadden, how to configure CDT? Would you give me some details? I am a newbie android developer.

Comment: I think this is related to the Indexer. Some related questions are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148235/eclipse-cdt-shows-semantic-errors-but-compilation-is-ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have fix this issue using the following method:

1. go to setting: properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
2. choose the "Includes" tab and select "GNU C++"
3. add new include directories:
   `${NDKROOT}\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.8\include`, where `${NDKROOT}` is environment for my android-ndk root directory

I hope it can help others encounter the same issue. Thanks for all your helps all the same.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see and problem in the code. So i think it is  indexing problem that we normally face while using Eclipse to do NDK development.

See below link for similar issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788

Indexing issue can be solved using the procedure specified here:

[Migrate a C program to Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924184/migrate-a-c-program-to-android-ndk)

**Summary:**
Using the Android GCC toolchain but changing the actual tools and modifying the discovery options so that the include paths and symbols are correct.

Answer (score 0):

C++ compiler is strict than C compiler by default. Try adding type casting in your code either in C style or C++ style -

```
memcpy((void *)rtn, (const void *)ba, (int)alen);
```