# "Invalid arguments" when porting C++ code to Android

Tags: android, c++, porting, invalid-argument

I am trying to port the following piece of C++ code to Android as part of some NDK work:

```
#include <fstream>

// ...

inline void trim(string & str, const string & delim = " \t\r\n")
{
    string::size_type pos = str.find_last_not_of(delim);
    if(pos == string::npos) str.erase(str.begin(), str.end());
    else
    {
        str.erase(pos+1);
        pos = str.find_first_not_of(delim);
        if(pos != string::npos) str.erase(0, pos);
    }
}
```

What I get is the following message at `str.erase(pos+1);` and `str.erase(0, pos)`:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> & erase(?, ?)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>    erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>)
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>     erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>,     __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>)
'
```

I tried what was suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924184/migrate-a-c-program-to-android-ndk) but it did not help. Instead, now I am getting a new message for `#include <fstream>`:

```
Unresolved inclusion: <fstream>
```

What do I need to do to resolve this? Thank you.

UPDATE: I am trying to add this piece of code to an existing C++ code in an Android project that built and ran fine. When I applied the change linked to above, I not only got the `unresolved inclusion` for fstream, I also got a bunch of other errors. For instance, for the following block form the existing code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>
```

I am also getting `Unresolved inclusion` errors. So it made things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line to `Application.mk` of your project.

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```